# How to get best fit unicode character mappings between encodings

Tags: winapi, unicode, internationalization, character-encoding, globalization

i have a UTF-16 string which contains some characters not directly representable in my local `Windows-1252` code-page:

```
6/23/2011 9:23:44 ᴀᴍ
```

i use [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the string to the local code-page (Windows-1252 on my north american computer):

```
WideCharToMultiByte(
    CP_ACP, //target CodePage
    0,      //flags
    Source, //my string, e.g. "6/23/2011 9:23:44 ᴀᴍ"
    length, //length in characters, e.g. 20
    buffer, //destination where to put the string
    bufferSize, 
    null,   //optional, character to use when character cannot be represented
    null);  //optional, out boolean that indicates if any character could not be represented
```

And the string comes out as:

```
6/23/2011 9:23:44 ??
```

Literally with question marks `0x3f  = "?"` for the non-representable characters.

When you look at the characters in the original string "ᴀᴍ", the two characters are:

- `ᴀ` U+1D00: Latin Letter Small Capital A
- `ᴍ` U+1D0D: Latin Letter Small Capital M

The unicode standard says [these are phonetic extensions, and for general text: use regular Latin](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D00.pdf). Which to me means the text should be converted to either:

```
6/23/2011 9:23:44 AM
```

or

```
6/23/2011 9:23:44 am
```

---

Another example could be `6′2″`:

- `′` U+2032: Prime
- `″` U+2033: Double Prime

When i convert that string to `Windows-1252` it becomes `6'2?` (apostrophe, `?`).

[Unicode entry for Prime](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf) lists apostrophe as an alternate:

```
2032   ′   PRIME
           = minutes, feet
           → 0027 ' apostrophe
           → 00B4 ´ acute accent
           → 02B9 ʹ modifier letter prime
```

Even though **prime** doesn't exist in the target codepage, `WideChartoMultiByte` **is** converting it to one of the closest equivalents (i.e. apostrophe).

On the other hand **Double Prime**:

```
2033   ″   DOUBLE PRIME
           = seconds, inches
           → 0022 " quotation mark
           → 02BA ʺ modifier letter double prime
           → 201D ” right double quotation mark
           ≈ 2032 ′ 2032 ′
```

is being mapped to nothing (`?`), yet some of the other items exist in my Windows-1252 encoding:

```
Character                                 Unicode  Windows-1252
========================================= =======  ============
″ double prime                            U+2032      -
" quotation mark                          U+0022     0x22
ʺ modifier letter double prime            U+02BA      -
” right double quotation mark             U+201D     0x94

′ prime                                   U+2032      -
' apostrophe                              U+0027     0x27
´ acute accent                            U+00B4     0xb4
ʹ modifier letter prime                   U+02B9
```

Even in the worst case where it *decomposes* the original `double prime` into `prime` `prime`: prime has an equivalent - since it already used it.

For the other characters there are also mappings:

```
Character                                 Unicode  Windows-1252
========================================= =======  ============
ᴀ Latin Letter Small Capital A            U+1D00      -
A Latin Capital Letter A                  U+0041     0x41
a Latin Small Letter A                    U+0061     0x61

ᴍ Latin Letter Small Capital M            U+1D0D      -
M Latin Capital Letter M                  U+004D     0x4d
m Latin Small Letter M                    U+006D     0x6d
```

How do i make `WideChartoMultiByte` do best fit mapping between encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can alter results of `WideCharToMultiByte()`. If you care enough to try different solution [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) might give you different results.

Personally, I haven't tried it, so I cannot guarantee results (who needs to convert from Unicode, anyway?) but I believe you should exercise [ICU Converters](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/converters). The nice thing about it, is that supports Unicode 6.0 (you probably do not need that, anyway).

Comment: Accepted for *can't do it*. i really don't want to have a ship a dll with my software in order to get one function to behave.

Comment: @Ian Boyd:  You can do it; it's just the Windows doesn't do it all for you.  You could write a preprocessor that does the fallback substitutions before passing it to WideCharToMultibyte.  It would require a sparse table built from the Unicode Character Database, which is a simple download.

Answer (score 1):

How well WideCharToMultiByte does might depend on the version of Windows you're using.  I believe newer versions use more complete tables.  Nevertheless, it will probably never cover all of the cases.  Since Windows prefers Unicode natively, there isn't much incentive for them to implement all of the fallback cases for the zillions of code pages out there.

Your choices are to use a library (like ICU as others have mentioned) or build your own pre-processor to handle fallback.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your target encoding, you can use the Posix-standardized `iconv` library (which is available for Windows, too) and convert from WCHAR_T or UTF-16 to your target encoding; iconv has a "transliterate" option which might turn all those special-needs characters of yours into their ASCII transliterates. Iconv is a bit lighter-weight than ICU and pretty widely available.